# Inverse Kinematics with OpenGL/Eigen3 : unstable Jacobian pseudoinverse

Tags: c++, opengl, eigen

I'm trying to implement simple inverse kinematics test using OpenGL, Eigen3 and ["Jacobian pseudoinverse"](http://math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/ikmethods/iksurvey.pdf) method.

The system works fine using "Jacobian transpose" algorithm, however, as soon as I attempt to use "pseudoinverse", joints become unstable and start jerking around (eventually they freeze completely - unless I use "Jacobian transpose" fallback computation). I've investigated the issue and turns out that in some cases Jacobian.inverse()*Jacobian has zero determinant and cannot be inverted. However, I've seen other demos on the internet (Youtube) that claim to use same method and they do not seem to have this problem. So I'm uncertain where is the cause of the issue. Code is attached below:

*.h:

```
struct Ik{
    float targetAngle;
    float ikLength;
    VectorXf angles;
    Vector3f root, target;
    Vector3f jointPos(int ikIndex);
    size_t size() const;
    Vector3f getEndPos(int index, const VectorXf& vec);
    void resize(size_t size);
    void update(float t);
    void render();
    Ik(): targetAngle(0), ikLength(10){
    }
};
```

*.cpp:

```
size_t Ik::size() const{
    return angles.rows();
}

Vector3f Ik::getEndPos(int index, const VectorXf& vec){
    Vector3f pos(0, 0, 0);
    while(true){
        Eigen::Affine3f t;
        float radAngle = pi*vec[index]/180.0f;
        t = Eigen::AngleAxisf(radAngle, Vector3f(-1, 0, 0))
            * Eigen::Translation3f(Vector3f(0, 0, ikLength));
        pos = t * pos;

        if (index == 0)
            break;
        index--;
    }
    return pos;
}

void Ik::resize(size_t size){
    angles.resize(size);
    angles.setZero();
}

void drawMarker(Vector3f p){
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(p[0]-1, p[1], p[2]);
    glVertex3f(p[0]+1, p[1], p[2]);
    glVertex3f(p[0], p[1]-1, p[2]);
    glVertex3f(p[0], p[1]+1, p[2]);
    glVertex3f(p[0], p[1], p[2]-1);
    glVertex3f(p[0], p[1], p[2]+1);
    glEnd();
}

void drawIkArm(float length){
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    float f = 0.25f;
    glVertex3f(0, 0, length);
    glVertex3f(-f, -f, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, length);
    glVertex3f(f, -f, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, length);
    glVertex3f(f, f, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, length);
    glVertex3f(-f, f, 0);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(f, f, 0);
    glVertex3f(-f, f, 0);
    glVertex3f(-f, -f, 0);
    glVertex3f(f, -f, 0);
    glEnd();
}

void Ik::update(float t){
    targetAngle += t * pi*2.0f/10.0f;
    while (t > pi*2.0f)
        t -= pi*2.0f;
    target << 0, 8 + 3*sinf(targetAngle), cosf(targetAngle)*4.0f+5.0f;

    Vector3f tmpTarget = target;
    Vector3f targetDiff = tmpTarget - root;
    float l = targetDiff.norm();
    float maxLen = ikLength*(float)angles.size() - 0.01f;
    if (l > maxLen){
        targetDiff *= maxLen/l;
        l = targetDiff.norm();
        tmpTarget = root + targetDiff;
    }

    Vector3f endPos = getEndPos(size()-1, angles);
    Vector3f diff = tmpTarget - endPos;


    float maxAngle = 360.0f/(float)angles.size();

    for(int loop = 0; loop < 1; loop++){
        MatrixXf jacobian(diff.rows(), angles.rows());
        jacobian.setZero();
        float step = 1.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < angles.size(); i++){
            Vector3f curRoot = root;
            if (i)
                curRoot = getEndPos(i-1, angles);
            Vector3f axis(1, 0, 0);
            Vector3f n = endPos - curRoot;
            float l = n.norm();
            if (l)
                n /= l;
            n = n.cross(axis);
            if (l)
                n *= l*step*pi/180.0f;
            //std::cout << n << "\n";

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                jacobian(j, i) = n[j];
        }

        std::cout << jacobian << std::endl;
        MatrixXf jjt = jacobian.transpose()*jacobian;
        //std::cout << jjt << std::endl;
        float d = jjt.determinant();
        MatrixXf invJ; 
        float scale = 0.1f;
        if (!d /*|| true*/){
            invJ = jacobian.transpose();
            scale = 5.0f;
            std::cout << "fallback to jacobian transpose!\n";
        }
        else{
            invJ = jjt.inverse()*jacobian.transpose();
            std::cout << "jacobian pseudo-inverse!\n";
        }
        //std::cout << invJ << std::endl;

        VectorXf add = invJ*diff*step*scale;
        //std::cout << add << std::endl;
        float maxSpeed = 15.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < add.size(); i++){
            float& cur = add[i];
            cur = std::max(-maxSpeed, std::min(maxSpeed, cur));
        }
        angles += add;
        for (int i = 0; i < angles.size(); i++){
            float& cur = angles[i];
            if (i)
                cur = std::max(-maxAngle, std::min(maxAngle, cur));
        }
    }
}

void Ik::render(){
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(root[0], root[1], root[2]);
    for (int i = 0; i < angles.size(); i++){
        glRotatef(angles[i], -1, 0, 0);
        drawIkArm(ikLength);
        glTranslatef(0, 0, ikLength);
    }
    glPopMatrix();
    drawMarker(target);
    for (int i = 0; i < angles.size(); i++)
        drawMarker(getEndPos(i, angles));
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I suspect you are not calculating the pseudo-inverse properly. I think you should use Eigen::SVD to compute it. See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Pseudoinverse).

Comment: "I suspect you are not calculating the pseudo-inverse properly" I've provided full source code for current Ik class, so if you're familiar with pseudo-inverse, you should be able to check if the computation is performed correctly.

Comment: Your use of OpenGL is the old deprecated pre-pipeline CPU based approach which does not use the GPU and shaders as intended.  Once you master your algorithm I encourage you to revisit writing shaders not CPU based code  (IE. glBegin is a red flag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your system is too stiff.

1. Try to use a the Eigen SVD methods: see http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-2.0/TutorialAdvancedLinearAlgebra.html. This is more computationally intense but also maybe more safe. If you are solving a aX=b problem it is best to use the methods dedicated to inverting a matrix. (a is your Jacobian and X is what you want).
2. Lastly, try to cheat the conditioning on your matrix by multiplying the diagonal by a factor like 1.0001. This won't change much the solution (especially for a game) but will enable better solving.
3. I am curious as to why you choose not to use a time iterative scheme such as RK4.

edit: I didn't read much of your extensive post so I have removed the reference to springs. I guess in your case the elements would have some form of mechanical interaction.

Comment: "your system is too stiff." System has no stiffness of any kind, there is no physical simulation, and there are only 4 joints. "Try to use a the Eigen SVD methods" I might give it a try but would prefer to figure out what's wrong with current pseudoinverse calculation. "elements as oscillating springs." They aren't springs and shouldn't behave like springs. "why you choose not to use a time iterative scheme" Because there is no "time". I need/want to know final joint configuration instantly, in current frame.

Comment: Regarding SVD: as far as I know, the problem with Ik is that system most likely has infinite number of solutions or no solution. I'm not certain that module you mentioned is suitable for this kind of problem.

Comment: #2 fixed the problem to some extent.

Comment: SVD gives you the "best" out of an infinite many. I know plenty of people who do robotics and they will SVD for exactly the problem you have described and I can known at-least one industrial robot that uses uses SVD.

Comment: "SVD" I'll check it out later. I would appreciate a code example, though.

Comment: I've tried your SVD(JacobiSVD in Eigen 3) suggestion (jt*j*angles = jt*diff, solve for angles), it looks like it works slightly faster and is more "stable" than jacobian pseudoinverse. However, I still have to multiply matrix diagonal by 1.0001 (otherwise it oscillates), but once it is done IK solver can handle chain of 64..100 links without any problem. In comparison, jacobian pseudoinverse requires larger diagonal multiplier in order to work even on 8..16 chain. Thanks for the suggestion, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
VectorXf solveViaSVD(const MatrixXf & jacobian,const VectorXf & diff) {
     Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixXf> svd (jacobian,ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV);
     return svd.solve(diff);
}
```

The problem is, as you said, that your method fails to compute the pseudo-inverse when (`J*J'`) is singular.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Pseudoinverse) says : "[the pseudoinverse] is formed by replacing every *nonzero* diagonal entry by its reciprocal". Computing `pinv(A)` as `inv(A'*A)*A'` fails the "nonzero" point.

Comment: Doesn't JacobiSVD need square matrices?

Comment: @SigTerm I tested this code on a 2x4 matrix and it works fine (apart from some gcc warnings I can't really understand).

Comment: Well, your example does work, but as far as I can tell, you don't need ans variable. I've upvoted you answer, however, I've already accepted Misha's answer and you recommend same thing as he does in his recommendation #1.

Comment: @SigTerm I initially used eigen2, and when i moved to eigen3 I just forgot to remove that 'ans'. I fixed my answer now.